# js pattern problems

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, functional-programming

I'm confused by a javascript design pattern I'm reading about:

```
var class = (function() {

  ...a bunch of code...

  return {

  .. some more code..

  ;

  // or, in some cases

  return function(constructorArgs) {

  };

})();
```

My question is:  What is the return statement doing?  Why is it there?  I'm confused because no-one wants to mention it or talk about it.

Comment: Do you know what the `()` in the last line does?

Comment: The `return` statement returns from the function it's in (what did you expect it to do?).

Comment: No.  I still don't understand.

Comment: @JaPerk14 Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-construct-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two distinct patterns that you're mentioning, I think.

#### Anonymous Closures

The first is using an anonymous function to wrap a block of code in order to create [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures):

```
var outer = (function() {
  var inner = "now you see me!";

  return inner + " now you don't"
})()
```

The anonymous function creates a new scope for `var`-defined variables.  In effect, this allows you to define variables that are only visible within that particular function.

In the example above, you have access to `inner` within the function, but it is not defined outside of it.

#### "Classes"

The second is a common pattern for defining "classes" in JavaScript:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
  function MyClass(arg) {
    this.arg = arg
  }

  return MyClass
})()
```

By defining the constructor function within a closure, you can be sure that your class is well contained.  It also enables you to share class-wide state or private helper methods without polluting the global namespace, or resorting to placing them as properties on your class constructor's prototype.

Comment: Wow. Someone's pretty trigger-happy with the old down-vote button. +1 for a good explanation of classes - I couldn't find the words.

Comment: I'm downvoting every answer that contains an incorrect explanation of "closure". Using an anonymous function that wraps a block of code is not a closure; it's just an anonymous function. The `MyClass` example doesn't involve a closure either. A closure is a function that refers to external local variables, i.e. variables from a surrounding scope.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) - a lexical closure is independent from a function; it just happens that in JavaScript, _functions define lexical closures within their bodies_.

Comment: The code executed within the block of _any_ JS function is being executed within a new closure.  It may not be referencing variables defined (lexically) outside of the closure's immediate scope - but that does not make the function body any less of a closure.

Comment: next time, rather than downvote every explanation you don't like, try to write your own. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

the code to the right of the `=` symbol is of this form: `(function(){})()`; What this does is compile a function - effectively the same as the following:

```
function temp() {
}

class = temp();
```

Inside the function in your example, however, there is another function being returned. What this means is that `class` is now also a function - the `class` function can then reference all of the variables etc. that are declared in the `temp` function, due to the closure effect referenced by [vtortola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307976/vtortola).

The idea of this is to allow the inner function to refer to some state that you don't want to have hanging around in your "global" (or semi-global) scope - it doesn't matter where the `class` method is called, or who by, it will *always* have access to that data.

Edit: It appears from the code that the purpose of the pattern in this case is to create a "class" type function - so then you'd be able to call it with the following code:

```
var myInstance = new class();
```

Though I've a feeling that none of the code will work as I'm reasonably certain that `class` is a reserved word...

Answer (score 2):

This is called a closure.

```
var myVar = (function (param1, param2){
    //do things
}('myParam1','myParam2')):
```

The javascript engine will immediatly execute what is between the parenthesis.

And the value of `myVar` will be what the function `function (param1, param2){ ... }` returns.

This function will use `('myParam1','myParam2')` as arguments.

You can write closure in two different ways :

```
(function (receivedArgs){
  //do things
})(yourArguments);
```

or

```
(function (receivedArgs){
   //do things
}(yourArguments));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a closure. A function is returning an inner function enclosing some variables in the middle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Cheers.